# Any idea how to avoid this assertion in DDTokenCache and what it means?

Tags: objective-c, parsing, ios, assertion

I am using `NSDataDetector` with `NSTextCheckingTypeLink` to search a string for links (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions) within it. Generally, it works fine, but when the string contains certain very long links (200+ chars) followed by a space and another word, I get this assertion:

```
> DDRequire failed: the following assertion will only be logged once
> 
> assertion on
> /SourceCache/MobileDataDetectorsCore/MobileDataDetectorsCore-154/Sources/PushDown/DDTokenCache.c:310
> "delta >= 0" failed :Bad shift in
> DDTokenCacheMoveStreamOffset, aborting
```

This is the kind of text that causes this:

```
> blog.somethingorother.com/2011/storynameetcmorestuff/utm_source/eedburnerutmmediumfeedutmcampaign/FeedanutmcontentGooglFeedfetcherutmcampaign/FeedanutmcontentGooglFeedfetcher/eedburnerutm_mediumfeedutmcampaign/FeedanutmcontentGooglFeedfetcherutmcampaign HEY
```

Does anyone know what's behind this or have any other insight into this?

Comment: You should file a [bug report](http://bugreport.apple.com) with this info, along with a sample project that reproduces the issue.

Comment: OK, will do. But I'm still hoping for a workaround that will not involve scrapping NSDataDetector.

Comment: For anyone else running this: It's filed with Apple under problem ID 8917104. You can reference that in your bug report, should you make one.

Comment: Smells like a framework bug.

Answer (score 1):

**Resolved: Problem is with UITextView data detectors.**

Please go through UIDataDetectorTypes:

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, UIDataDetectorTypes) {
UIDataDetectorTypePhoneNumber   = 1 << 0,          // Phone number detection
UIDataDetectorTypeLink          = 1 << 1,          // URL detection    
#if __IPHONE_4_0 <= __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED
UIDataDetectorTypeAddress       = 1 << 2,          // Street address detection
UIDataDetectorTypeCalendarEvent = 1 << 3,          // Event detection
#endif    

UIDataDetectorTypeNone          = 0,               // No detection at all
UIDataDetectorTypeAll           = NSUIntegerMax    // All types
};
```

**If you set UIDataDetectorTypeAll or UIDataDetectorTypeAddress or  UIDataDetectorTypeCalendarEvent then iOS creates problems on iOS5.0 and Above.**

```
textview.dataDetectorTypes=UIDataDetectorTypeAll;
```

Or

```
textview.dataDetectorTypes=UIDataDetectorTypeAddress | UIDataDetectorTypeCalendarEvent;
```

Then sometimes it creates problem on iOS5.0 and above.

**So you need to set data detectors explicitly :**

```
textview.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink | UIDataDetectorTypePhoneNumber;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could preprocess the text replacing those links that make trouble.

Comment: You could try to insert a # or ? behind the link before the _space_HEY

Comment: downvoter -- please explain. this sounds like a valid workaround :)