# UITableViewCells with UITextView causing Bad shift in DDTokenCacheMoveStreamOffset

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController that is populated with several cells, each with its own UITextView that displays a given string from an array. About one time in twenty, opening the UITableViewController causes a crash with the following message in the console:

> assertion on
>   /SourceCache/MobileDataDetectorsCore_Sim/MobileDataDetectorsCore-355/Sources/PushDown/DDTokenCache.c:360
>   "delta >= 0" failed :Bad shift in DDTokenCacheMoveStreamOffset,
>   aborting

The only other reference to a similar problem is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761357/any-idea-how-to-avoid-this-assertion-in-ddtokencache-and-what-it-means),  but my TextViews don't have long links in them-- they do have data detectors enabled for links and phone numbers, but few of the TextViews have either.

What should I do to fix this? And can it be done without removing the data detectors?

Answer (score 0):

I'm only getting this in the simulator and not on the device itself.. I believe it is a bug.

Comment: I've had it happen in the device, but not as frequently as simulator. For now I'm just leaving the data detectors out in the one view controller where the problem happens most often, and things seem okay.

Comment: Ya actually I see the issue now on the device...  Going to see if any of these solutions help.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18962742/uitextview-link-detection-in-ios-7/18968687#18968687

Comment: This appears to be fixed in 7.1.

Comment: Good to hear! I switched my UITextViews to TTTAttributedLabels, which seems to have cut down on the problem as well. https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel